# Probleme shell_exec with php using ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, sh, shell-exec

I have a problem with `shell_exec`. I need to run `sh` file from `php` file

In ubuntu :

```
<?php
echo shell_exec ('sh ./myScript.sh');
?>
```

But it didn't work.

---

I tried the following, in Windows, and it worked:

```
<?php
exec('c:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c START myScript.bat');
?>
```

Comment: And what's problem ? Are you sure `./myScript.sh` points to file which you  specified ? or what not worked?

Comment: myScript.sh in the same folder with my page runScript.php
in /var/www/html/

i  test myScript.sh using terminal Sh ./myScript.sh and work

Comment: Yea but shell_exec maybe start from other directory like at place where shell binary is located i would try full path first

Comment: i tray it 
echo shell_exec ('sh var/www/html/myScript.sh');
no rslt :/

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the command like this:

```
shell_exec ('sh /var/www/html/myScript.sh');
```

Comment: Not working 
myScript.sh generate from Talend Job

#!/bin/sh
cd `dirname $0`
ROOT_PATH=`pwd`
java -Xms256M -Xmx1024M -cp .:$ROOT_PATH:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/routines.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:$ROOT_PATH/php_0_1.jar: local_project.php_0_1.Php --context=Default "$@"

Comment: Is that the error you are getting? It seems like the script is running the file but the error is coming from myScript.sh. Have you tried running the script from the terminal in Linux?

Comment: no this is my code in file myScript.sh

#!/bin/sh
cd `dirname $0`
ROOT_PATH=`pwd`
java -Xms256M -Xmx1024M -cp .:$ROOT_PATH:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/routines.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:$ROOT_PATH/php_0_1.jar: local_project.php_0_1.Php --context=Default "$@" 

yes i tried runnig it with Sh ./myScript.sh  and run

Comment: When you run it from PHP, does it throw any errors?

Comment: no errors 
i try with sample shell file hello word and work :3 but my shell file  need to show it show a msg box

Comment: I am not sure if you can do that. You will have to ask the question first (Message box) and then on user selecting yes do whatever your shell script does on yes selected.

Comment: @SadDev and if you run script on it's own from terminal does it work ?

Comment: @MarekMaszay yes :/

Comment: @MarekMaszay i can send you my zipped folder if you wana and thx